# What media players can be accessed by a Logitech G15 media keys?

Tags: windows-xp, logitech-keyboard

I have a Logitech G15 keyboard and know that the media buttons work on Windows media player without the application having focus.  What other media players are supported by those keys without requiring focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The media-player keys send messages to apps that are standardised by Microsoft, so they will work with any application that is set up to recognise them. Windows Media Player does this by default but some apps have to be configured to recognise them. In Winamp for example, you have to go to the Global Hotkeys section of the Preferences and check the "Enable default multi-media key support" option.

Answer (score 1):

According to the configuration for the Media Display widget, it supports:

- iTunes
- MediaLife
- MusicMatch
- RealPlayer
- Sonique
- Sonique 2 Beta
- Winamp
- Windows Media Player 9+
- Yahoo! Music Jukebox

I've only tried with iTunes, and that seems to work fine.

Comment: Windows Media Player works fine too.

Comment: These options are for the LCD panel to display the status of those apps, they're not a means of configuring the multi-media player buttons which is what the OP was asking.